# Xcode- UICollectionView shouldSelect vs didSelect

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uicollectionview

```
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        if let selectedItem = collectionView?.indexPathForCell(sender as UICollectionViewCell) {

        if segue.identifier == "next" {

            var second: SecondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as SecondViewController
            second.itemNumber = selectedItem.row

        }
        }
    }

 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {

        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: cell)
        } 
        return true
    }

    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    }
```

The function `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` works perfectly the way `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` is supposed to be. `didDeselectItemAtIndexPath` works with some cells and not the other in a random fashion. So what is the problem here?

EDIT: It was a typo, I used didDeselectItemAtIndexPath instead of didSelectItemAtIndexPath

Comment: Maybe because you use did**De**select instead of didSelect?

Comment: The ultimate worst feeling ever about coding, is when you feel so stupid :(

Comment: We've all been there ...